# C - How to correctly free memory of a pointer to array of n char ((*p)[n])?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory, memory-management

I've written the following program to read strings from file and store they to arrays which fixed number of columns and variable number of rows in a struct.

```
FILE *fp;
typedef struct {
char  (*date)[12],
      (*content)[50],
      (*amount)[10];
} list;
list in;
int i,lines;
fp = fopen("book.txt","r");
lines = 100;
in.date = malloc(lines * 12 * sizeof(char));
in.content = malloc(lines * 50 * sizeof(char));
in.amount = malloc(lines *10* sizeof(char ));

printf("%-12s%-40s%-10s\n","Date","Content","Amount");

for(i = 0;i <lines;i++){
    fscanf(fp,"%s\t%[a-z|A-Z| ]\t%s\n",in.date[i],in.content[i],in.amount[i]);
    printf("%-12s%-40s%-10s%\n",in.date[i],in.content[i],in.amount[i]);
}
```

I can allocate memory for rows, but program will stop working when free memories as follow :

```
for(i = 0;i < lines;i++){
        free(in.date[i]);
        free(in.content[i]);
        free(in.amount[i]);
    }
```

how do I correctly free them from memory?

Comment: If you're allocating `in.date`, why you want to free `in.date[i]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're allocating an *array* of things but attempting to free each *individual* thing whereas what you need to do is free the *array.*

Generally, cleaning up means freeing every single object that you allocated (and in reverse order if there's any cross-link between them). If that object is an array, free the array. Don't try to free parts of the array.

As per `C11 7.22.3.3 The free function /2`:

> ... if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function, ... the behavior is undefined.

That would mean you need to do something like:

```
in.date = malloc (lines * 12);    // sizeof(char) is ALWAYS 1
in.content = malloc (lines * 50); //   so TOTALLY unnecessary.
in.amount = malloc (lines * 10);
:
// use them here
:
free (in.amount);
free (in.content);
free (in.date);
```

You should probably also check each allocation to see if it fails as well, since continuing under those circumstances is likely to cause a great deal of grief.